# How to commit consumer offsets using Camel-kafka?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using apache camel to integerate with my kafka messaging. Also i am using JAVA DSL to consume messages from kafka endpoint.

Using apache kafka API's its known how to commit consumer offsets with given properties toggling.

if i disbale auto commit in camel-kafka component how can i commit offsets in apcahe camel then?

I am using below endpoint to disable auto commit in Apache Camel

```
kafka.consumer.uri = kafka://{{kafka.host}}?zookeeperHost={{zookeeper.host}}&zookeeperPort={{zookeeper.port}}&groupId={{kafka.consumerGroupId}}&topic={{kafka.topic.transformer_t}}&{{kafka.uri.options}}
kafka.uri.options = autoCommitEnable=false
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: not really but check latest specs in Camel-Kafka if they have something. I stopped using Camel-Kafka for not supporting commit Offset manually.

Comment: This was a show stopper for me too.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947180/how-to-manually-control-the-offset-commit-with-camel-kafka

Answer (score 1):

Support for manual offset commit was added in [CAMEL-11933](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11933) and is supported since version 2.21.0. You can enable it with option [allowManualCommit=true](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html). This option will expose header `CamelKafkaManualCommit`, holding instance of [`KafkaManualCommit`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-kafka/2.21.0/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaManualCommit.html), which you can then use e.g. in `Processor`.

```
from("kafka:topic?groupId=group&autoCommitEnable=false&allowManualCommit=true")
  //...
  .process(exchange -> {
     exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.MANUAL_COMMIT, KafkaManualCommit.class).commitSync();
  });
```